# How to get the library paths of a meson dependency?

Tags: libraries, meson-build, build-dependencies

**Use case:**  I have a dependency that falls back to a subproject:

```
./
./subprojects/
./subprojects/mylib.wrap
```

`src/meson.build` contains:

```
mylib_dep = dependency('mylib')  # Searches for mylib with pkg-config then fall backs to mylib.wrap.
myexec_exe = executable ('myexec', 'myexec.c', dependencies : mylib_dep)
```

Dependency `mylib_dep` provides libraries, which, if not installed on the system, make the main executable of my project unusable:

```
$ meson build && cd build && meson compile src/my_exec
...snip'd...
$ src/my_exec
src/my_exec: error while loading shared libraries: libmylib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My testing script `build/tests/mytests.sh` is `configure_file`d from `tests/mytests.sh.in` to indicate the location of `myexec`, and I'd like to pass to it the library paths, so that it can adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and run the executable.  For instance, in `tests/meson.build`:

```
conf_data = configuration_data ()
conf_data.set_quoted ('MYEXEC_PATH', myexec_exe.full_path ())
conf_data.set_quoted ('MYLIB_PATH', mylib_dep.??????)
mytest_exe = configure_file (input : 'mytests.sh.in', output : 'mytests.sh', configuration : conf_data)
```

and in `tests/mytests.sh.in`:

```
MYEXEC_PATH=@MYEXEC_PATH@
MYLIB_PATH=@MYLIB_PATH@
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(dirname "$MYLIB_PATH"):$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$MYEXEC_PATH
```

**Question:**  What should go at the `??????` above?  In other words, given a dependency object, how can I extract the libraries within it, and get their full paths?

Comment: See [this](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_returned_dep.html#depget_variable)

Comment: @droptop: I have, thanks, I'm not sure how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in meson you wouldn't configure_file this, you'd pass the library/executable(s) to the script as arguments in the test command:

```
test(
  'mytest',
  find_program('mytest.sh')
  args : [executable_target, library_target, ...],
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure how this helps, though: I still don't know how to extract the library path from the dependency object.

Answer (score 0):

It can be frustrating trying to get this sort of info out of Meson.  Fortunately, if Meson used CMake to find the dependency, you may be able to get the library path from the underlying CMake variables, which are available in the Meson dependency object.  Eg, something along the following lines worked for me:

```
mylib_dep = dependency('mylib')
if mylib_dep.found()
   mylib_path = mylib_dep.get_variable(default_value : '', cmake : 'PACKAGE_LIBRARIES')
   message('Library path is:', mylib_path)
endif
```